# keras/theano loss or op that uses full network

Tags: theano, keras

I am looking for a way to implement the following network structure (currently using Keras, might be theano however):

Assume we're given some simple network, but it is not possible to compute the desired loss based on this output directly, instead another operation is needed and the loss will be defined based on the output of this operation. However, this operation does not only need the output of the network but the full network object (eg its gradient).

How can this be done? I think the operation could be performed either in a custom layer on top of the network or in a custom loss function - but for neither version I see a way to access the full network. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you talking about adding an additional layer to a Keras model?

Comment: yes, but not just any new layer: the layer needs access not only to its input but also to the network structure (e.g. be able to compute the gradient of the network up to the point where my custom layer starts). I am not sure if a layer is the perfect solution, so maybe I only use the network without my custom layer and define a loss function instead that performs my custom operation that includes the network gradient. However to do so, the loss function needs access to the full network while AFAIK it only gets (y_true, y_label) as an input.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume we're given some simple network, but it is not possible to compute the desired loss based on this output directly, instead another operation is needed and the loss will be defined based on the output of this operation. However, this operation does not only need the output of the network but the full network object (eg its gradient).

Say, you have the following model.

```
import keras.applications.vgg16 as vgg16

model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
model.summary()
```

For example, now you want to delete the last layer of this model which is actually predicts a category (a vector of length 1000 because imagenet has 1000 categories) for the input image.

```
# Remove last Linear/Dense layer.
model.layers.pop()
model.outputs = [model.layers[-1].output]
model.layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
model.summary()
```

Now, lets add a linear layer (with output size 10) to this model and use the output of the modified neural network model.

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

You will get a vector (of length 10) as an output from this model.

You can compile and train the model using `model.compile()` and `model.fit()` functions. You can set what type of loss function you want to use to train the model.

Comment: it seems my questions was not clear: the new layer or the custom loss function should use the FULL network (e.g. be able to compute the networks gradient), not just the output neurons. However, for the loss function, it seems it always [needs to be] (https://keras.io/objectives/) a function with arguments (y_true, y_loss), i.e. it does not have access to the full network. Likewise, a [custom layer only gets its direct input values] (https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) as an argument to call and no access to the full model either as far as I can see.

Comment: I am not understanding what you meant by - "the new layer or the custom loss function should use the FULL network"? I guess your understanding about neural networks is wrong. Because whenever neural network does some mistake, it updates all the model parameters associated with the full network, not only related to a specific layer! So, when you said, "loss function does not have access to the full network" - it doesn't make sense! A neural network tries to learn a classification task, loss function represents how much the network makes mistake! and update weight parameters accordingly.

Comment: Trust me, I do understand networks ;) Obviously I would not ask how to design such a new network op/layer or loss if it was standard to do it. Now, if you trust me that I know what I am doing, this becomes a pure implementation issue. How could I access the network from within a loss function or how would I have to design a new layer and custom op to get access to the full network? I am aware that I might have to implement gradients myself.